# Removing modulus to express x in terms of a

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to find the point at which these two lines intersect.$$f(x) = |x - a| + a $$ $$g(x) = 4x + a$$ I've currently got $$4x = |x - a|$$and I know that to remove the modulus I need to square both sides, but I'm not sure what to do from there to get x = something

Comment: If you square both sides, you get a quadratic equation.  How do you normally solve a quadratic equation?

Comment: @Bye_World I expanded the quadratic, but when I tried to group the terms I ended up with a in terms of x rather than the other way around. I think I'm having a bit of a blank

Comment: Grouping might be difficult with that parameter $a$.  Why not try the quadratic formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x<a$, your line is $f(x)=2a-x$.

If $x>a$ your line is $f(x)=x$

$g(x)=4x+a$ for all values of x.

Solve the first equation:

$4x+a=2a-x$.

$5x=a$.

**Solution 1** --> $\boxed{\displaystyle x=\frac{a}{5}}$.

Solve the second equation

$x=4x+a$

$-3x=a$

**Solution 2** --> $\boxed{\displaystyle x=-\frac{a}{3}}$

So which one do we use?

If $a$ is positive, then we use the first solution.

If $a$ is negative, then we use the second solution.

Answer (score 2):

Squaring is not necessary.  When $x\ge a$, we have

$$4x=|x-a|=x-a\implies x=-\frac a3\ge a\implies a\le0$$

When $x<a$, we have

$$4x=|x-a|=a-x\implies x=\frac a5<a\implies a>0$$

Comment: If I was to answer that way in an exam context, would I write something along the lines of "let x>a or x<a"?

Answer (score 1):

You can either square both sides and then use the quadratic formula to solve for $x$ or you can just note that $|x-a|=4x$ implies that $x-a=4x$ or $x-a = -4x$. Then just solve each of these equations individually.